# C++ allocating memory using array

Tags: c++, memory-management

concerning this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771868/how-to-allocate-memory-space-without-using-malloc-or-new-operator) on how to allocate memory without using new or malloc, suppose I have a structure linked list

```
struct stack {
 string info;
 stack next*;

};
```

The answer provided says use global byte array. How would I implement an linked list by allocating to global byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have a memory pool declared in data segment and have your own memory allocation function.

```
char myMemoryPool[10000000]; // global variable (can be enclosed in namespace)
```

And you have to write your own memory manager:

```
void* MyMemoryAlloc (size_t SIZE)
{
 //... use SIZE
}
```

Usage:

```
A* p = (A*)MyMemoryAlloc(sizeof(A) * 3);
```

Or more precisely,

```
template<typename T>
T* MyMemoryAlloc (unsigned int UNITS)
{
//... use (sizeof(A) * UNITS)
}
```

Usage:

```
A *p = MyMemoryAlloc<A>(3);
```

Comment: what code goes in to MyMemoryAlloc? Also what is the different between the first and second version?

Comment: `MyMemoryAlloc` contains a **memory manager** written by **you**, which allocates memory from the global variable and also releases it when something like `MyDealloc` is called. 1st version of the `MyMemoryAlloc()` is equivalent of `malloc`, which returns a `void*` raw pointer and 2nd version is typesafe version like `new/new[]`.

Comment: What would a most primitive memory manager look like? Could you think of an example?

Comment: @Mark, I dont have much idea but you can get lot of links from google. e.g. http://www.scribd.com/doc/3499563/Building-your-own-memory-manager-for-C-C-projects

Comment: This doesn't work, as there is no guarantee that `myMemoryPool` is correctly aligned.  And he'll still need `new` in order to construct the objects.

Comment: @James: Dynamically allocated large character arrays are required to be strictly aligned, but I can't find any requirement for large char arrays with static lifetime.  Either which way, `MyMemoryAlloc` is going to have to worry about alignment on a per-block basis, this logic will probably subsume any misalignment of the entire pool.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Dyanmically allocated character arrays are required to be suitably aligned for any type.  Statically defined ones, no.  And the response here involves a statically defined `char[]`.

Comment: @James: That's probably why I couldn't find a requirement.  Anyway, the allocator has to provide alignment explicitly, because the "first free byte" is going to become unaligned pretty easily.

Comment: @Ben If you're writing a generalized allocator, the simplest solution is just to round up all requests to a multiple of the strictest alignment requirement.  For a specialized allocator, you're always allocating sizeof(T), so if the start of the buffer is aligned, so will all of the future pointers.

Comment: @James: True.  Of course, for a specialized allocator, you'd just define a static array of `T`, which will be properly aligned.

Comment: @Ben You might; in this case, I probably would.  But you might not want to initialize all of those objects until you needed them.  Especially if the object type didn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @James: That's a good point.  You could inhibit construction with a `union` I guess.  Which is almost the same as what you've done in your answer, but you can just have `union Element { Element* next_free; struct stack content; }`, which will be properly aligned for the actual type.  (Do you need to define a constructor for the union, when the members have constructors, to choose which one gets constructed, or does the first one automatically get constructed by default?)

Comment: @Ben §9.5/1: "A union shall not be used as a base class. An object of a
class with a non-trivial constructor, a non-trivial copy constructor, a
non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy assignment operator cannot
be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects."

Comment: @James: I guess I'm thinking of C++0x:  "If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator, or destructor, the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted for the union."  So much more useful.

Comment: And: "In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new operators to change the active member of a union."

Comment: @Ben Sounds like they've fixed `union`, so that it can actually be useful (other than for very low level stuff like I was doing here).  I'd missed that; it's good news.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a pointer, use an index into the array.  (Actually, a pointer is nothing but an index into the byte array representing all virtual memory).  You'll have to keep track of which indexes (or ranges of indexes) are used.

This is called a pool-based allocator.

Comment: do you know how to implement one or please point to a reference on how to implement one?

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what the question is supposed to mean.  You could
just declare a large block of `stack`, and use them, perhaps using a bit
vector of some sort to keep track of which ones are free or not, or
simply keeping the free elements in their own list (since you have a
pointer in the type).  A more generic solution (not counting on the
pointer) would involve a union:

```
union StackPoolElement
{
    StackPoolElement* next;
    double dummyForAlignment;
    unsigned char data[sizeof(Stack)];
};
static StackPoolElement pool[10000];
```

You can then overload `operator new` and `operator delete` in `Stack` to
allocate from this pool.  (But of course, that's using `new` and
`delete`.  Which is what makes the question so stupid; a generic
solution, which doesn't depend on the presence of a pointer in the
object, will need some form of `new` to initialize the object.)

The one thing that you can't do is just declare a global byte array,
since there is no guarantee that it will be correctly aligned (and I've
used more than one compiler where it wouldn't be).  If you want a byte
array, it must be in some sort of a `union` to guarantee sufficient
alignment.  (On all of the machines I know, adding a `double` to the
`union` is sufficient.  But it's not guaranteed either.)  And if you're
using a byte array, you still need some form of `new` to construct your
objects; either you overload `operator new` and `operator delete` in
your class, to allocate using the byte array (and then allocate
instances of the class using `new` and `delete`, as normal), or you use
some form of placement new.

Comment: Besides that, there's the problem that `struct stack` in the question appears to have a member of type `std::string`, and THAT uses `new` (not even placement `new`) extensively.  If indirect use of placement `new` isn't prohibited, one could use `std::array` or `std::vector` with a custom allocator in order to construct the objects.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yes.  The entire question seems poorly defined.