# C - (C99) , how to create a stack struct, without using stdlib.h (without malloc)

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, stack

I have a homework for tomorrow, and am asked to make a dynamic (resizable) stack, that saves chars.

This thing have been driving me crazy, been on it all day. I did it using the stdlib and it was done. But can't seem to figure out how to allocate memory without malloc.. help would be really appreciated. These are some code snippets that I have used (with stdlib):

```
    struct STACK
    {
        int size;
        int capacity;
        char *memory;
        int folder_number;
    };
typedef struct STACK stack;
```

My main starts like this:

```
int main()
{
    stack mystack;
    stack_init(&mystack);
```

Initializing the stack function:

```
void stack_init(stack *s)
{
    s->size=1;
    s->capacity=INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    s->memory=malloc(s->capacity);
    s->memory[0]='\0';
    s->folder_number=1;
}
```

I have all kind of functions for my program, and when I insert new char into the stack, I check if I have reached the max capacity, if so , I call the following func:

```
void double_memory(stack* s)
{
    char *tmp = malloc((s->capacity)*2);

    for (int i=0; i<(s->capacity); i++)
        tmp[i]=s->memory[i];
    free(s->memory);
    s->capacity *= 2;
    s->memory=tmp;
}
```

Now, I have been trying for at least 6 hours in a row, to try and figure out how to do it otherwise (without using stdlib.h), searched a lot on google, with no success. any help or advice would be really!! appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I have started at university around 2 months ago, I don't know about platforms..etc, the last 2 things we learned were pointers, and small information about malloc, b4 that we simply learned about functions hhh..., and before that, VERRY basic coding..

Comment: Does it have to be portable ?

Comment: I'm very sorry, didn't understand wt u mean by portable

Comment: Does it have to run on more than one implementation class ? Should I provide an answer that works only for POSIX, would it still be fine ?

Comment: You should look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771868/how-to-allocate-memory-space-without-using-malloc-or-new-operator)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess it has to be, I did the program with no malloc, simply by using a pointer for the array (without determining size). It worked perfectly on my windows. But when I ran the tests on our university tester, it didn't even compile, they use unix system.

Comment: You are certainly missing some advice of your teacher of what is allowed or not, and how to attack this problem. In any case SO is not right forum for such type of demands. SO is a Q&A forum for technical questions.

Comment: I think the answer is to use recursion so each stack item is created dynamically.

Comment: I agree with Jens - I'm pretty certain that at 2 months into a programming course, you are NOT supposed to solve a resizeable stack without using malloc.

Comment: "*I have a homework for tomorrow, ...*" start taking care earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Use a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stack {
        FILE * fp;
        } stack = {NULL} ;
#define ZENAME "zestack"

void stack_init (struct stack *sp);
void stack_exit (struct stack *sp);
void stack_push (struct stack *sp, int ch);
int stack_pop (struct stack *sp);

void stack_init (struct stack *sp)
{
if (sp->fp) fclose(sp->fp);
sp->fp = fopen(ZENAME , "wb+" );
if (!sp->fp) fprintf(stderr, "Fopen(%s) failed\n", ZENAME  );
}

void stack_exit (struct stack *sp)
{
if (sp->fp) fclose(sp->fp);
sp->fp = NULL;
}

void stack_push (struct stack *sp, int ch)
{
fputc(ch, sp->fp);
}

int stack_pop (struct stack *sp)
{
int ch;
long int oldpos, newpos;

if (!sp->fp) return -1;
oldpos = fseek(sp->fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
if (oldpos < 0) { stack_exit (sp); return EOF; }

ch = fgetc(sp->fp);
newpos = fseek(sp->fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
fprintf(stderr, "Oldpos = %ld Newpos = %ld\n", oldpos, newpos );
return ch;
}
int main(void)
{

int ch;
stack_init ( & stack);
stack_push ( & stack, '1');
stack_push ( & stack, '2');
stack_push ( & stack, '3');
stack_push ( & stack, '4');

while(1) {

        ch = stack_pop( &stack);
        fprintf(stdout, "Pop = '%c' (0x%x)\n" , ch, (unsigned) ch) ;
        if (ch < 0) break;
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Neat trick, although isn't the use of anything from `stdio.h` the use of an external library which the OP is saying he can't use?

Comment: Could be. But the OP only mentioned malloc() and stdlib.h The other trick (mmap()) is rather unix-specific and also requires systemcalls, thus stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` on most POSIX-compliant platforms simply uses `mmap` with anonymous mapping under the hood ... so you could call that function instead using the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag to allocate memory into a memory pool for use by your stack implementation.  Here is a link to the LINUX man-page for `mmap`: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html

For efficient use of your allocated memory pool, I would suggest setting up some type of simple linked-list memory manager ... in other words you want to call `mmap` once to allocate a large chunk of memory, and then use your own user-defined `malloc` and `free` calls to manage the memory pool.

**UPDATE:** From your comments you're now saying that you can't use *any* external libraries.  Therefore your only other option is to designate a static array for your memory pool since allocating memory dynamically from the heap at runtime requires intervention from the OS, and that can't be done without a system call.

Here is a simple linked-list memory manager system you could use (note: I haven't debugged it, but since it's homework, that's your job :-)

```
static unsigned char heap[MEMORY_POOL_SIZE];

typedef struct memory_block
{
    unsigned long size_bytes;
    unsigned char block[];
} memory_block;

typedef struct free_block
{
    unsigned long size_bytes;
    struct free_block* next;
} free_block;

//initialize our memory pool free-store
static char free_list_initialized = 0;
static free_block* free_list_head = NULL;

void* malloc(unsigned long size_bytes)
{
    //initialize the free-store if it's never been used before
    if (!free_list_initialized)
    {
        free_list_head = (free_block*)&heap[0];
        free_list_head->size_bytes = MEMORY_POOL_SIZE - sizeof(memory_block);
        free_list_head->next = NULL;
        free_list_initialized = 1;
    }

    //search the free-list for a memory block that is at least size_bytes
    free_block* current = free_list_head;
    free_block* prev = NULL;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->size_bytes >= (size_bytes + sizeof(free_block)))
            break;

        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    //did we reach the end of the list without finding anything?
    if (current == NULL)
        return NULL;  //out-of-memory!

    memory_block* temp = NULL;

    //trim the block of memory if the one we found is larger than the requested size
    if (current->size_bytes > (size_bytes + sizeof(free_block)))
    {
        temp = (memory_block*)current;
        current = (free_block*)((unsigned char*)current + size_bytes + sizeof(memory_block));

        current->size_bytes = current->size_bytes - (size_bytes + sizeof(memory_block));
        temp->size_bytes = size_bytes;

        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = current;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = current->next;
        temp = (memory_block*)current;
    }

    return (void*)&temp->block;
}

void free(void* ptr)
{
    free_block* temp = (free_block*)((unsigned char*)ptr - sizeof(unsigned long));
    temp->next = free_list_head;
    free_list_head = temp;

    return;
}
```

Comment: we r not expected to use that, we r not expected to use almost anything beyond struct, and pointers / arrays.. etc. and we r not allowed to include any libraries.

Comment: Sorry, you just said without `stdlib` and without `malloc` in your OP ...

Comment: @Shady: It's spelled "are", not "r". Please don't use silly abbreviations; they just make your comment harder to read.

Comment: @Shady: "*we r not expected to use that ...*": to use what? Jason does not use anthing external?

Comment: @alk: Originally I suggested using `mmap`, but the OP is saying absolutely no external dependencies ... I don't know, it seems kinda advanced to me to get into making your own free-store when you simply want to design a resizeable stack.